# BountyAmount is missing in latest Stack Exchange Data Dump (14-Mar-2017)

Tags: support, data-dump

We are doing a research project on Stack Overflow data. So I have downloaded the latest Stack Overflow data dump from [the Stack Exchange archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (14-Mar-2017). But the table `Votes` (or any other table) doesn't contains the `BountyAmount` field.

Can you please let me know how can we get this value?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the database structure but could it be it's it's own table?

Comment: unfortunately not existing on seperate table too. I searched in Blogs, so far could not find any clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BountyAmount` field is not missing. Here are the first 10 occurrences:

```
  <row Id="1472821" PostId="98225" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="4234" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="350" />
  <row Id="1472847" PostId="296603" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="4234" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="550" />
  <row Id="1472968" PostId="309711" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="2140" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="250" />
  <row Id="1473097" PostId="222716" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="2635" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="150" />
  <row Id="1473113" PostId="74883" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="2822" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="200" />
  <row Id="1473162" PostId="280604" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="22092" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="150" />
  <row Id="1473187" PostId="435466" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="267" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="150" />
  <row Id="1473321" PostId="457087" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="6805" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="100" />
  <row Id="1473362" PostId="209198" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="14260" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="100" />
  <row Id="1473376" PostId="476049" VoteTypeId="8" UserId="41956" CreationDate="2009-01-27T00:00:00.000" BountyAmount="100" />
```

Note that `BountyAmount` is only present if `VoteTypeId` is `8` or `9`: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm talking about latest archive in https://archive.org/download/stackexchange (Date = 14-Mar-2017). There in table : Votes, missing both fields: UserId & BountyAmount.

Comment: Here is the etries in archived Votes.xml:

<row Id="113059" PostId="23281" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2008-08-22T00:00:00.000" />
  <row Id="113060" PostId="23267" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2008-08-22T00:00:00.000" />
  <row Id="113061" PostId="23264" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2008-08-22T00:00:00.000" />
  <row Id="113062" PostId="23327" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2008-08-22T00:00:00.000" />
 <row Id="113063" PostId="19687" VoteTypeId="2" CreationDate="2008-08-22T00:00:00.000" />

Comment: @Menaka I did download the latest data, via the torrent. The entries you linked have a `VoteTypeId` of `2`.

Comment: Just FYI, I downloaded the votes.xml (so not via the torrent) and that file also does have the bountyamount for rows with an votetypeid="8" attribute. That votes.xml is also complete.